# 3rd conditional form ("If I had X, I would ..."?)

Tags: conditionals

> If I had learnt that, I would have been doing much better right now.

Is that correct? If not, how do you say it correctly?

Comment: Not in my book. I suggest, *If I had learnt that, I would **be doing** much better **right now.***   or alternatively, *If I had learnt that, I would **have been doing** much better **by** now*.  The meanings are slightly different.

Comment: Yes, what you have is correct, but it is not the only way to say that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You suggest:

> If I had learnt that, I would have been doing much better right now

However you have mixed tenses.

I suggest:

1. *If I had learnt that, I would **be doing** much better **right now.***

or alternatively and with a different meaning,

2. *If I had learnt that, I would **have been doing** much better **by** now*.

Answer (score -1):

If I had learned that, I would be doing much better right now.

Comment: Yes, in US it's always 'learned'. In UK it can be 'learnt' or 'learned' http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/learn

Comment: @polly34 - Welcome to the site. For future reference, it's always a good idea to provide some supporting evidence when submitting an answer. This may be in the form of cited sources, published examples or definitions etc. Without them, your answer is likely to be voted down and possibly deleted.